# MySql workbench read only results grid issue

Tags: mysql-workbench

I tried this on MySql workbench version 6.3 and 5.2.47:

`select * from my_table`
returns the results table which I can edit

However when I do a `select` query and include each field of the table:

`select field1, field2, ..., fieldn from table`

I cannot edit the results table (it shows the 'ready-only' blue icon in the bottom right of the results table, with message on hover that says `the select statement is missing primary key or or unique non-nullable columns`)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out when I type the field name in the correct case as in the table it works. So if field name is `ProductID`, doing `select productid` will show the results correctly, but workbench won't allow me to edit the results table. 
Instead, `select ProductID` works. Would be nice if someone could explain why that is, and if possible to configure workbench to ignore case when selecting fields? Thanks!